# Using Resources Folder in Unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, resources, assets, hololens

I have am developing a HoloLens project that needs to reference .txt files. I have the files stored in Unity's 'Resources' folder and have them working perfectly fine (when run via Unity):

```
string basePath = Application.dataPath;
string metadataPath = String.Format(@"\Resources\...\metadata.txt", list);

// If metadata exists, set title and introduction strings.
if (File.Exists(basePath + metadataPath))
{
      using (StreamReader sr = new StreamReader(new FileStream(basePath + metadataPath, FileMode.Open)))
    {
         ...
    }
}
```

However, when building the program for HoloLens deployment, I am able to run the code but it doesn't work. None of the resources show up and when examining the HoloLens Visual Studio solution (created by selecting build in Unity), I don't even see a resources or assets folder. I am wondering if I am doing something wrong or if there was a special way to deal with such resources.

Also with image and sound files...

```
foreach (string str in im)
{
      spriteList.Add(Resources.Load<Sprite>(str));
}
```

The string 'str' is valid; it works absolutely fine with Unity. However, again, it's not loading anything when running through the HoloLens.

Answer (score 43, accepted):

You can't read the Resources directory with the `StreamReader` or the `File` class. You must use [`Resources.Load`](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Resources.Load.html).

**1**.The path is relative to any Resources folder inside the Assets folder of your project.

**2**.Do **not** include the file extension names such as *.txt*, *.png*, *.mp3* in the path parameter.

**3**.Use forward slashes instead of back slashes when you have another folder inside the *Resources* folder. backslashes won't work.

**Text files**:

```
TextAsset txtAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("textfile", typeof(TextAsset));
string tileFile = txtAsset.text;
```

Supported *TextAsset* formats:

*txt* *.html* *.htm* *.xml* *.bytes* *.json* *.csv* *.yaml* *.fnt*

**Sound files**:

```
AudioClip audio = Resources.Load("soundFile", typeof(AudioClip)) as AudioClip;
```

**Image files**:

```
Texture2D texture = Resources.Load("textureFile", typeof(Texture2D)) as Texture2D;
```

**Sprites - Single**:

Image with *Texture Type* set to *Sprite (2D and UI)* and

Image with *Sprite Mode* set to *Single*.

```
Sprite sprite = Resources.Load("spriteFile", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
```

**Sprites - Multiple**:

Image with *Texture Type* set to *Sprite (2D and UI)* and

Image with *Sprite Mode* set to *Multiple*.

```
Sprite[] sprite = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("spriteFile") as Sprite[];
```

**Video files (Unity >= 5.6)**:

```
VideoClip video = Resources.Load("videoFile", typeof(VideoClip)) as VideoClip;
```

**GameObject Prefab**:

```
GameObject prefab = Resources.Load("shipPrefab", typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;
```

**3D Mesh (such as FBX files)**

```
Mesh model = Resources.Load("yourModelFileName", typeof(Mesh)) as Mesh;
```

**3D Mesh (from GameObject Prefab)**

```
MeshFilter modelFromGameObject = Resources.Load("yourGameObject", typeof(MeshFilter)) as MeshFilter;
Mesh loadedMesh = modelFromGameObject.sharedMesh; //Or   design.mesh
```

**3D Model (as GameObject)**

```
GameObject loadedObj = Resources.Load("yourGameObject") as GameObject;
//MeshFilter meshFilter = loadedObj.GetComponent<MeshFilter>();
//Mesh loadedMesh = meshFilter.sharedMesh;

GameObject object1 = Instantiate(loadedObj) as GameObject;
```

**Accessing files in a sub-folder**:

For example, if you have a *shoot.mp3* file which is in a sub-folder called "*Sound*" that is placed in the *Resources* folder, you use the forward slash:

```
AudioClip audio = Resources.Load("Sound/shoot", typeof(AudioClip)) as AudioClip;
```

**Asynchronous Loading**:

```
IEnumerator loadFromResourcesFolder()
{
    //Request data to be loaded
    ResourceRequest loadAsync = Resources.LoadAsync("shipPrefab", typeof(GameObject));

    //Wait till we are done loading
    while (!loadAsync.isDone)
    {
        Debug.Log("Load Progress: " + loadAsync.progress);
        yield return null;
    }

    //Get the loaded data
    GameObject prefab = loadAsync.asset as GameObject;
}
```

*To use*: `StartCoroutine(loadFromResourcesFolder());`

Comment: I see, that makes sense. Then my next part would be that I also have image and sound files (in resources) that I am using resources.load to retrieve. Those work in Unity but not when I deploy to the HoloLens either.

Comment: *I've answered many of these questions about Resources folder and one few hours ago and most of them with the-same answer but different problem in title or description. I've decided to put together a solution that will cover most of this problems and file types to prevent providing duplicate answer in the future.* Check my edit and let me know if you have a question.

Comment: This is a practical and complete reference for resources which I have been looking for :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to load text file from resource please do not specify file extension
just simply follow the below given code

```
private void Start()
{
    TextAsset t = Resources.Load<TextAsset>("textFileName");
    List<string> lines = new List<string>(t.text.Split('\n'));
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        Debug.Log(line);
    }
}
```

`debug.Log` can print all the data that are available in text file

Answer (score 0):

You can try to store your text files in streamingsasset folder. It works fine in my project