# Unity Resources.Load <Sprite> return null

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, sprite

Yes, I have read all the topics with similar problems. 
However mine is not solved yet :(

So could you please take a look into it?

Like everyone else, I'm trying to change a sprite of an object via code.
The sprite file itself is in "Assets/Resourses" folder.
The import settings state the texture type of the imported file is "Sprite(2D and UI)".

I've tried the following methods:

```
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("1");
```

and

```
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = Resources.Load("1") as Sprite;
```

and

```
Sprite s = Resources.Load("1") as Sprite;
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = s;
```

and

```
Sprite s = Resources.Load<Sprite>("1");
gameObject.GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().sprite = s;
```

All of them replace existing object sprite with "None(Sprite)", which I guess, means "null".

Any help would be really appreciated!

Comment: Have you put image into Resource folder ??

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> The sprite file itself is in "Assets/Resourses" folder.

That's the problem. The folder must be named *Resources* **not** *Resourses*. It's not [*Resource*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43175064/unity-resources-load-sprite-return-null#comment73424576_43175064) too.

It has to be named named *Resources*. Once you fix the folder name, you can use the snippet below to read the `Sprite`.

```
Sprite sprite = Resources.Load("1", typeof(Sprite)) as Sprite;
```

if the sprite is set to multiple mode then use this;

```
Sprite[] sprite = Resources.LoadAll<Sprite>("1") as Sprite[];
```

You can find other ways to load Sprites [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41326276/3785314).

Comment: most stupid design choice to force users to put their resources in a hardcoded folder name