# Texture2D is working in Editor but not in Android device

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, textures

I am trying to change the texture of my object with this code:

```
Texture2D baileyburlwood = Instantiate(Resources.Load("bailey burlwood") as Texture2D);
    myObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = baileyburlwood;
```

It is working perfectly fine in the editor, the texture changes but when I tried to run it in my android device, my object just goes black. There is also no error or any warning. Pls help! Thanks!

I am using Unity 5.5.1f btw

[image: I added a screenshot of where the file is located]

Comment: Is value baileyburlwood changing during gameplay?

Comment: what do u mean by changing?

Comment: I see you are loading texture file from resource folder but is it really necessary doing it this way? Because you can just make "public Texture2D baileyburlwood; " and then declare it in editor. Also I dont recommend using empty spaces in file names.

Comment: @Janella Where did you put the "bailey burlwood" file? I think you should select that file and post a screenshot of it. I want to know the settings of that file if it is not a prefab.

Comment: hi @Programmer, I added the screenshot in my question

Comment: Ok. Check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the screenshot in your updated question, the image you want to load is called *bailey burlwood.jpg* which is already in the *Resources* folder..

Herein lies the problem:

```
Instantiate(Resources.Load("bailey burlwood") as Texture2D);
```

You instantiate prefabs, scripts and components **not** normal classes like `Texture2D`.

Your code would have worked if *bailey burlwood.jpg* is *bailey burlwood.prefab* and you load it with `GameObject prefab = Resources.Load("shipPrefab", typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;` but that's not the case here.

Since the *"bailey burlwood"* file is a JPG file, you should load like this:

```
Texture2D baileyburlwood = Resources.Load("bailey burlwood") as Texture2D;
myObject.GetComponent<Renderer>().material.mainTexture = baileyburlwood;
```

Note that there is no `Instantiate` function involved. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326248/using-resources-folder-in-unity/41326276#41326276) post for how to load other image files with different image settings when using the Resources folder.