# loading objects from folder in runtime unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a project that uses an object, but I have a problem 
how to load an object and this textures in runtime by scripting C# in unity because I was searching and I haven't found any method.

Thanks and sorry for English

Comment: Load from the Resources folder? Look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326248/using-resources-folder-in-unity/41326276#41326276).

Comment: Don't use Resources, use [Asset Bundles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/AssetBundle.html)

Comment: @Draco18s Ok , but Asset Bundles is depending on WWW class , can I depend with folder directory to Get object and textures , Or can I use WWW to load from folder , if yes how to do it ?

Comment: I don't know. I haven't started using Asset Bundles myself, they're pretty new.

Comment: Do you mean "spawning" an asset object to the scene on runtime? if yes its easy, learn about [Prefab](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/Prefabs.html) and [Instantiate](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/InstantiatingPrefabs.html).

Comment: @itay_421 No , I want load or open object from folder and show it in my project