# Unity: Saving/Loading Sprites as Json

Tags: c#, json, unity-game-engine

I was following a tutorial where I need to save the sprite that belongs to an object.
I am creating a database of items and would of course want the correct image to come with the item. This is how I built my Item database:

**ItemObject**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ItemObject{

    public int id;
    public string title;
    public int value;
    public string toolTip;
    public bool stackable;
    public string category;
    public string slug;
    public Sprite sprite;


    public ItemObject(int id, string title, int value, string toolTip, bool stackable, string category, string slug)
    {
        this.id = id;
        this.title = title;
        this.value = value;
        this.toolTip = toolTip;
        this.stackable = stackable;
        this.category = category;
        this.slug = slug;
        sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("items/" + slug);
    }
```

**ItemData**

```
[System.Serializable]
public class ItemData {

    public List<ItemObject> itemList;

}
```

I then Save/Load ItemData.itemList. That works great. As you can see I use "slug" to load the sprite of my Item, slug is basically a code-friendly name (ex: golden_hat), then I have the same name for my Sprite.

This also works great, but Unity saves the Sprite InstanceID, which always changes on start, so if I exit Unity and load my data, it will get the wrong Image.

**My Json:**

```
{
    "itemList": [
        {
            "id": 0,
            "title": "Golden Sword",
            "value": 111,
            "toolTip": "This is a golden sword",
            "stackable": false,
            "category": "weapon",
            "slug": "golden_sword",
            "sprite": {
                "instanceID": 13238
            }
        },
        {
            "id": 1,
            "title": "Steel Gloves",
            "value": 222,
            "toolTip": "This is steel gloves",
            "stackable": true,
            "category": "weapon",
            "slug": "steel_gloves",
            "sprite": {
                "instanceID": 13342
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

So I'm guessing it wont work to do it this way, is there some other way to save a Sprite in Json? Or do I have to load the correct Sprite at runtime every time using my "slug"?

Comment: You **should not** save sprites in your game. You should use AssetBundles or the Resources API. As for saving it, save the **path** of the AssetBundles or [Resources](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41326276/3785314) folder

Comment: @Programmer Thanks, Ill save the path to Resources folder for now. And start looking into AssetBundles.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A more appropriate way would be to save the texture as byte [] then your json contain the name or url of the byte [].

```
    {
        "id": 1,
        "title": "Steel Gloves",
        "value": 222,
        "toolTip": "This is steel gloves",
        "stackable": true,
        "category": "weapon",
        "slug": "steel_gloves",
        "sprite": "steelgloves"
    }
```

Then when you grab the json, you convert to C# and look for the the byte array. Once you have the byte array, you can reconstruct the sprite:

```
byte [] bytes = File.ReadAllBytes(path);
Texture2d tex = new Texture2D(4,4);
tex.LoadImage(bytes);
Sprite sp = Sprite.Create(tex, new Rect(0, 0, tex.width, tex.height), new Vector2(0.5f,0.5f));
```

Comment: Accepted cus it answers my question. However am going to just save the path to the Resources asset instead :)

Answer (score 3):

If you're using `JsonUtility` for serialization, you can implement `ISerializationCallbackReceiver` in order to receive serialization callbacks. That way you can load the correct sprite based on the stored path after the object has been deserialized. You'll also avoid resource duplication.

```
[Serializable]
public class ItemObject : ISerializationCallbackReceiver
{
    public void OnAfterDeserialize()
    {
        sprite = Resources.Load<Sprite>("items/" + slug);
        Debug.Log(String.Format("Loaded {0} from {1}", sprite, slug));
    }

    public void OnBeforeSerialize() { }

    (...)
}
```

If you *really* want to store the sprites directly in the JSON, consider serializing the raw texture data taken from `Sprite.texture.GetRawTextureData()` (probably store the binary data in a [base64 string](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.convert.tobase64string(v=vs.110).aspx)) and recreating it at runtime using  `Sprite.Create()`. The `ISerializationCallbackReceiver` trick will apply here too.

As an additional note, if it fits your requirements, definitely consider dropping the JSON-based object database in favour of using [Scriptable Objects](https://unity3d.com/learn/tutorials/modules/beginner/live-training-archive/scriptable-objects). This way you can easily reference UnityEngine objects without having to resort to using the Resources folder (which is not recommended unless necessary).

Comment: Thanks, +1 for mentioning ScriptableObjects. But as I understand those are saved internally. And I would like players to be able to mod my game without too much issue. Which Json fits very well for

Comment: This was the method I was attempting to use, but unfortunately, you can't make calls to Resources.Load during OnAfterDeserialize or OnBeforeSerialize.