# Loading 3d models in unity editor and in deployed app

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, import, model, assets

I've created an app that make use of models that in editor I load using `UnityEditor.AssetDatabase.LoadAssetAtPath`. If I try to deploy the app, it says that Unity Editor can't be used.

So which is the best strategy that I should apply to load my models at run time, outside the editor?

Answer (score 0):

Always check that the API you are using is **not** in the `UnityEditor` namespace. If it's just an Editor plugin, you can wrap it around `UNITY_EDITOR`.

```
#if UNITY_EDITOR
using UnityEditor;
#endif
```

But it's not an Editor plugin so that wound't work.

> So which is the best strategy that I should apply to load my models at
>   run time, outside the editor?

There are really two ways to load files in Unity

**1**.AssetBundles(Recommended)

The best way is to use AssetBundles. Create a folder in the Assets folder and na e name is *"StreamingAssets"*. Create AssetBundles then put the AssetBundles there. You can use Unity's `WWW` API with `Application.streamingAssetsPath` as the path to load it.

```
public string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(Application.streamingAssetsPath, "MyFile");
public string result = "";
IEnumerator Example() {
    if (filePath.Contains("://")) 
    {
        WWW www = new WWW(filePath);
        yield return www;
        result = www.text;
    } else
        result = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(filePath);
}
```

**2**.Resources folder

Create a folder named *"Resources"* then put all your files there. You can then load it with the Resources API. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41326276/3785314) post has more information about this method. I do think you should avoid using this method but it's really worth to be mentioned.

```
TextAsset txtAsset = (TextAsset)Resources.Load("textfile", typeof(TextAsset));
string tileFile = txtAsset.text;
```