# Using NPOI in Unity

Tags: c#, excel, unity-game-engine, npoi

I am new to the whole npoi thing but I want to put some values to specific cells in excel sheet ("exceltest.xls , cell A1,A2 ) and read the answer from cell **A3**. The problem is the excel doesn't recalculate the formula and send the old value here is the code

```
string path = "d:/testexcel2.xls";

HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileStream(@path, FileMode.Open));

ISheet sheet = book.GetSheet("sheet1");
IRow datarow = sheet.GetRow (0);
datarow.GetCell (0).SetCellValue (22222);
datarow.GetCell (1).SetCellValue (3333);
sheet.ForceFormulaRecalculation=true;
ICell res2 = sheet.GetRow (0).GetCell (2);
res=res2.NumericCellValue.ToString();
Debug.Log (res);
```

How to save the file?

Comment: And this relates to `unity3d` how?

Comment: i am making the program in unity , all the values will be entered in input fields

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution

```
string path =  "testexcel2.xls";
        Debug.Log (path);
        no1s = no1.text;
        no2s =  no2.text;

    HSSFWorkbook book = new HSSFWorkbook(new FileStream(@path, FileMode.Open));

        ISheet sheet = book.GetSheet("sheet1");
        IRow datarow = sheet.GetRow (0);
        datarow.GetCell (0).SetCellValue (no1s);
        datarow.GetCell (1).SetCellValue (no2s);
        HSSFFormulaEvaluator.EvaluateAllFormulaCells (book);
        ICell res2 = sheet.GetRow (0).GetCell (2);
        res=res2.NumericCellValue.ToString();
        result.text = res;
        Debug.Log (res);
```

But How can i load the file from resources?

Comment: [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326248/using-resources-folder-in-unity/41326276#41326276) is how to save and load from thr Resources folder

Comment: i tried but you can't load  HSSFWORKBOOK from resources, it gives an error