# Start function not called when script instance is created

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, unity3d-2dtools

I followed this [tutorial](http://www.studica.com/blog/unity-ui-tutorial-scroll-grid) to form a table in Unity.

What I like to do is 
(1)I like to change the Cell's width x height dynamically in the code.
(2)I like to set height of the first row of grids higher than the rest.

My code is

```
public class PopulateCellsToLeftPanel : MonoBehaviour {
    public GameObject cell;
    private int numberOfCells;
    private float cellWidth;
    private float cellHeight;

    public PopulateCellsToLeftPanel(int num, float w, float h)
    {
        numberOfCells = num;
        cellWidth = w;
        cellHeight = h;        
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {

        GameObject newObj; // Create GameObject instance
        GridLayoutGroup grid = this.GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>();
        grid.cellSize = new Vector2(cellWidth, cellHeight);
        int numRow = numberOfCells % 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRow; i++)//row
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)//column
            {                
                newObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(cell, transform);
                if(i%2 == 0)
                    newObj.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
                else
                    newObj.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Then from the main class, I tried to set using the class's constructor.

```
public class Historycanvas : MonoBehaviour, IPointerClickHandler
{
    PopulateCellsToLeftPanel pL;
    pL = new PopulateCellsToLeftPanel(30, CellWidth, CellHeight);

}
```

But numberOfCells, cellWidth and cellHeight are always 0. Is that `void Start()` is called earlier than class constructor?

Is it possible to set the height of first row of cells in the grid is different from the rest?

EDIT:

I did Debug.Log at both constructor function and Start function as below.

```
public PopulateCellsToLeftPanel(int num, float w, float h)
    {
        Debug.Log("i am from constructor start");
        numberOfCells = num;
        cellWidth = w;
        cellHeight = h;
        Debug.Log("i am from constructor end");
    }
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {
        Debug.Log("i am from Start start");
        GameObject newObj; // Create GameObject instance
        GridLayoutGroup grid = this.GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>();
        grid.cellSize = new Vector2(cellWidth, cellHeight);
        int numRow = numberOfCells % 4;
        for (int i = 0; i < numRow; i++)//row
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)//column
            {                
                newObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(cell, transform);
                if(i%2 == 0)
                    newObj.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
                else
                    newObj.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
            }
        }
        Debug.Log("i am from Start end");
    }
```

But I am surprised as Debug.log from Start() function was printed earlier than those from constructor(). Please look at in the following attached image. That is why my variables are always 0.
[image]

EDIT 2:

I tried to make a separate public function to instantiate image into grid as below, but images are not populated. Does it work only in Start()? Because if I put the same thing in Start() function, it works and the only issue with Start() is those parameters (int rows, float cellWidth, float cellHeight) I can't change dynamically. I need to change dynamically.

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

public class PopulateCellToLeftPanel : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject cell; 

    // Use this for initialization
    void Start()
    {


    }

    public void Plot(int rows, float cellWidth, float cellHeight)
    {
        Debug.Log("cell width " + cellWidth + " cell height " + cellHeight + " num rows " + rows);
        GameObject newObj; // Create GameObject instance
        GridLayoutGroup grid = this.GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>();
        if (grid == null)
            Debug.Log("grid is null");
        grid.cellSize = new Vector2(cellWidth, cellHeight);

        for (int i = 0; i < rows; i++)//row
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 4; j++)//column
            {
                newObj = (GameObject)Instantiate(cell, transform);
                if (i % 2 == 0)
                    newObj.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.white;
                else
                    newObj.GetComponent<Image>().color = Color.red;
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Main Class

```
public class main: MonoBehaviour
{
   PopulateCellToLeftPanel pL = null;
    void Start()
    {
       pL = gameObject.AddComponent<PopulateCellToLeftPanel>();
       pL.Plot(13, CellWidth, CellHeight);
    }
}
```

My console output is as follow and grid is null.

[image]

Comment: Create a different GridLayout Group for the first row, later you can add those two GridLayout Groups into a Vertical Group if you like.

Comment: Your `Start` function is not being called. You need to read the duplicate to see what you are doing wrong. Also note that using `Debug.Log` can be helpful in the future to determine if a function is being called or not. Finally, this is C# and I fixed the title of this question to reflect your actual problem

Comment: @Programmer thanks, I'll look into that. But if I hard-code the values in the PopulateCellsToLeftPanel class, it works. I don't think Start() is not called. Let me check again.

Comment: `Start` function in your `PopulateCellsToLeftPanel` script can never be called with your current code. Please use `Debug.Log` to prove what I just said. If it get's called then Unity has changed lately but I doubt that

Comment: @Programmer Please look at in EDIT in the OP. I tested with Debug.Log and found that Start is called earlier than Constructor.

Comment: Thanks for the EDIT. With my version of Unity(2017.2.0b5) it's not called. I suspect that you attached `PopulateCellsToLeftPanel` to a GameObject from the Editor and that GameObject is what's showing the second log to you or the behavior changed. Regardless, *don't you see the warning you are getting in the Editor?*  Please read the duplicate. You should not not use constructor if you inherit from `MonoBehavior`.  Just the read duplicate and fix that.

Comment: @Programmer thanks, now I am clear. For the class inherited from MonoBehavior, how can I have cellWidth and cellHeight change dynamically?

Comment: Add a `public` function to the `PopulateCellsToLeftPanel ` **instead** of 
 using the constructor. After instancing the class with `AddComponent` (as described in the duplicate), call that public function to set the `cellWidth` and `cellHeight`.

Comment: @Programmer Images can be instantiated into grid only in Start()? I create a new public function and instantiate there. But it doesn't work.

Comment: *"Images can be instantiated into grid only in Start()?"* I never mentioned `Start` in my last comment and don't understand your comment. Please post your new code. I will take a look

Comment: @Programmer I added in EDIT 2.

Comment: The code looks fine to me. The `Plot` function should be in the `PopulateCellsToLeftPanel`...It should be working. If not, please tell me which part is not working. You don't have to add another edit. Just continue editing your **EDIT 2**.  If you can update both classes in your EDIT 2 that would be good. I want to see the complete code you have now. Please add Debug.Log too and explain what exactly do not work.

Comment: It's looking good. `grid` is `null` which means that `this.GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>()` is failing. You are supposed to attach `GridLayoutGroup` to **the-same** GameObject the `PopulateCellsToLeftPanel` script is attached to then `this.GetComponent<GridLayoutGroup>()` should work. You can also do that from script by replacing that with `grid = this.AddComponent<GridLayoutGroup>()` .

Comment: Also not that `public GameObject cell;` is initialized that will likely be your next issue. If `cell` is supposed to be a prefab, you can load it from the [Resources folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326248/using-resources-folder-in-unity/41326276#41326276) `pL.cell = Resources.Load("yourCellPrefab", typeof(GameObject)) as GameObject;` or if it is just a new GameObject, you can use the `new` keyword on it: `pL.cell = new GameObject("Cell");`.

Comment: @Programmer thanks it works. Since the code is attached to container inside Scroll View, I need to get GetComponent of that container object.