# How to prevent "public" in Unity?

Tags: c#, oop, unity-game-engine

Being a student and having finished my school year I studied the development of Unity in C # to learn how to use the engine but also and above all to have fun.

One of the advantages of Unity is that you can pass a game object parameter directly in drag/drop, but for this to be possible it is necessary that the said variable is in public, which goes against what I have learned in class (the attributes must be private as often as possible).

My question was, how to make sure to have the same result with private attributes, i.e., recovered the game object manually without using the drag/drop system?

Thanks in advance and sorry for my English level.

[image]

Comment: the reasons to make everything private are much less valid in Unity than in general C#, most of the time you can make pretty much everything public and pay no penalty (other than general mess)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is not necessary to mark the variable as `public` in order to make it appear in the Editor. Just just put the `SerializeField` attribute on top of the `private` variable and it should show up in the Editor.

```
[SerializeField]
private GameObject cam1;
```

---

You can also do the opposite which is make `public` variable not show in the Editor. This can be done with the `HideInInspector` attribute.

```
[HideInInspector]
public GameObject cam1;
```

> But there is another method in Unity to get a GameObject, by avoiding
>   drag/drop ?

Yes. Many ways.

If the GameObject already exist in the scene then You can with one of the `GameObject.FindXXX` functions such as `GameObject.Find`, `GameObject.FindGameObjectWithTag`

For example,

```
[HideInInspector]
public GameObject cam1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    cam1 = GameObject.Find("Name of GameObject");
}
```

If the GameObject is just a prefab then put the prefab in a folder named *Resources* then use `Resources.Load` to load it. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41326248/using-resources-folder-in-unity/41326276#41326276) for more thorough examples.

---

Finally if you just want to get the component of that GameObject, just like your `cam1` variable which is not a GameObject but a component, First, find the GameObject like I did above then use the `GetComponent` function to get the component from it.

```
private Camera cam1;

// Use this for initialization
void Start()
{
    GameObject obj = GameObject.Find("Main Camera");
    cam1 = obj.GetComponent<Camera>();
}
```

Comment: Oh thanks for your quick answer. 
But there is another method in Unity to get a GameObject, by avoiding drag/drop ?

I mean by "classic" method like code ?

example (totally wrong, just to illustrate): cam1 = *code to access the GameObject*

Comment: Woa thank you so much for your answer that was really helpful :)

Comment: I noticed you may also want to initialize components like the `cam1` variable. See my another edit. You're welcome!

Comment: Brilliant answer!

Comment: Well answered @Programmer.

Comment: You can also use unity's tag feature to find things much more efficiently. 

Its great to see people taking an interest in proper use of access modifiers. You may want to check out a concept called "dependency injection".